# Re-write PHP code in node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I need to migrate from PHP to node.js, but am having some trouble. I tried and wrote something in node. Can someone help and explain how to improve this. The main problem is how to migrate PHP classes to node. Right now result is 0. Is it a good idea to write PHP classes as javaScript objects or better to write them like functions? Function CrcResult must return something?

```
class CrcResult {

public $Name = '';
public $Crc = 0;

}

 class CrcParams {

public $Name;
public $Array;
public $Init;
public $XorOut;
public $RefOut;
public $Poly;
public $RefIn;
public $Check;

}

$CRC_32_ = new CrcParams();
$CRC_32_->Init = 0xFFFFFFFF;
$CRC_32_->Name = "CRC-32";
$CRC_32_->XorOut = 0xFFFFFFFF;
$CRC_32_->RefOut = TRUE;

$CRC_32_->Poly = 0x4C11DB7;
$CRC_32_->RefIn = TRUE;
$CRC_32_->Check = 0xCBF43926;
$CRC_32_->Array = array(
  0xB40BBE37, 0xC30C8EA1, 0x5A05DF1B, 0x2D02EF8D,.....);

class Crc32 {
public function ComputeCrc($crcParams, $data) {
$crc = $crcParams->Init;

if ($crcParams->RefOut) {
    foreach ($data as $d) {
        $crc = $crcParams->Array[($d ^ $crc) & 0xFF] ^ ($crc >> 8 & 0xFFFFFF);
    }
} else {
    foreach ($data as $d) {
        $crc = $crcParams->Array[(($crc >> 24) ^ $d) & 0xFF] ^ ($crc << 8);
    }
}

$crc = $crc ^ $crcParams->XorOut;

$result = new CrcResult();
$result->Crc = $crc;

return $result;
}

}

$crcList = array($CRC_32_);    
$crc_algo = $CRC_32_;
$crc_calculator = new Crc32;

$crcResult = $crc_calculator->ComputeCrc($crc_algo, $output_data);
$calcdata = $crcResult->Crc & 0xFFFFFFFF;

$ar = unpack("C*", pack("L", $calcdata));
```

Bellow my node.js script

```
 function CrcResult() {
 var name = '';
 var Crc = 0;
 };

var CrcParams  = {};

CrcParams.Init = 0xFFFFFFFF;
CrcParams.Name = "CRC-32";
CrcParams.XorOut = 0xFFFFFFFF;
CrcParams.RefOut = true;
CrcParams.Poly = 0x4C11DB7;
CrcParams.RefIn = true;
CrcParams.Check = 0xCBF43926;
CrcParams.Array = [
    0xB40BBE37, 0xC30C8EA1, 0x5A05DF1B, 0x2D02EF8D,....];


function ComputeCrc(crcParams, data) {
var crc = crcParams.Init;

if (crcParams.RefOut) {
  data.forEach(function(item, data) {
  crc = crcParams.Array[(item ^ crc) & 0xFF] ^ (crc >> 8 & 0xFFFFFF);
    });
} else {
    data.forEach(function(item, data) {
        crc = crcParams.Array[((crc >> 24) ^ item) & 0xFF] ^ (crc << 8);
    });
}

crc = crc ^ crcParams.XorOut;

var result = new CrcResult();
result.Crc = crc;

return result;
}


var crcList = CrcParams;    
var crc_algo = CrcParams;
```

Comment: i need to migrate that code

Comment: I find similar projects, it's looks like that but i can't fix.                            
 var output_data = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','56'];
    
    var crcResult = Crc32(crc_algo, output_data);
    var calcdata = CrcResult.Crc & 0xFFFFFFFF;

console.log(calcdata);    using like that